# bash script to korn schell script

Tags: linux, unix, sh

Have the below bash script statements, need help to convert them to korn shell script. using as is in korn shell getting date: Not recognized flag: -

```
ndays=3


# work out our cutoff date
MM=`date --date="$ndays days ago" +%b`
DD=`date --date="$ndays days ago" +%d`
```

Comment: I believe `date` is a separate program from the shell it's running on. It should make no difference. I tested your script in `ksh` on my box and had no problems.

Comment: I am getting the same error date: Not recognized flag: -

Comment: What happens, when you are in `ksh` and you run `date --date="30 days ago" +%b` ?  Do you get the same error, or does it spit out `Jan` ?

Comment: Also, it shouldn't make a difference, but is your `ksh` shell also on a different box, or is this the same box and you are just switching between `bash` and `ksh`?

Comment: With out shell script, at $ sign I executed date..... command and getting the same error date: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]

Comment: Show output of `date --version | head -n 1` and `uname -s`

Comment: Getting this
date: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]
and: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
uname: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
-s: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

Comment: Got this working using this instead, 
MM=`TZ=GMT+77 date +%b`
DD=`TZ=GMT+77 date +%d`

Comment: You're asking the wrong question: this has **nothing** to do with bash vs ksh. You probably want `date program on $OS1 is different from date program on $OS2` -- just let us know what the variables are.